# What is this hole used for on my kitchen sink?

Tags: home, kitchen, sink

In my apartment's kitchen sink, besides the tap, I find there is a cap.

[image]

When I unscrew the cap, I find there is a pipe or a hole that connect to somewhere (probably into dishwasher, but I'm not very sure). Does anyone have ideas about what this hole used for? Thanks!

[image]

Comment: That is the dishwasher air gap. Instead of having the dishwasher drain connecting to a tailpiece into the sink drain, which can end up with drain water backing up into the dishwasher, an air gap prevents this.

That said, I can't see anything about this question that is on topic here.

Comment: @RoryAlsop Great answer, and I agree. Stack Exchange should have a "general knowledge" community.

Comment: Can you also rotate the images?

Comment: Perhaps Home Improvement, DIY: https://diy.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

The hole you are talking about is the dishwasher air gap.

Rather than having the dishwasher drain connecting to a tailpiece into the sink drain, which can result in drain water going into the dishwasher, that air gap stops this.

Answer (score 1):

That hole is for a liquid dish detergent pump. A container of liquid soap goes there. It looks like the bottom of container is in there,and only the pump is missing.